# Rails js.erb template code not fired when I render a partial within it, why is this happening?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a app that allows users to post microposts and when a micropost is posted I use ajax and jquery to update the post on the page with out the page refreshing.

Up until a few days ago this was working fine but all of a sudden it works randomly, some times it won't work and some times it will. The micropost is posted and database is updated but the js template I render doesn't seem to get fired most of the time.

**Microposts controller create action:**

```
def create
     @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])

        respond_to do |format|
            if @micropost.save
            format.js   { render :post_on_wall }
            end
        end

end
```

**Post_on_wall js template:**

```
$('form#new_micropost').off().on('ajax:success', function(e){
  alert('working');

    e.preventDefault();

    var micropostsContainer = $(this).parent('div.microposts');


    micropostsContainer.find('div.postsContainer').prepend('<%= j render("users/partials/micropost") %>');
    micropostsContainer.find('div.postHolder:first').hide().slideDown(250);
    micropostsContainer.find('textarea#micropostBox')
        .removeClass("micropost_content_expanded")
        .addClass("micropost_content")
        .val("");
    micropostsContainer.find('div#micropostOptions').addClass('micropostExtraOptions');
    micropostsContainer.find('div#postOptions').hide();
    micropostsContainer.find('div.imagePreview').css({
                                                  marginBottom:'0px',
                                                  marginTop:'0px'
                                                  })
                            .children().remove();

});
```

This where it gets strange. If I delete all code inside the js template except for the alert it then get's fired. With all the code put back the alert doesn't get fired. Now if I remove  the erb code that renders the micropost partial and add some text in a string there the js template alert is fired and the page is updated with the text.

I have no idea why this is happening. I even went back to a version of my app from a  few days ago and I get the same issue. The only thing I've changed would be the rails version. I  upgraded from 3.2.0 to 3.2.3.

Any way taking into account the microposts are still being posted to the DB any idea why I'm having this JS Ajax issue? I'm actually close to scrapping the use of remote_to in my forms and just using straight JQuery $.ajax instead but I shouldn't have to. I like to take advantage of what rails offers.

Here is my stack trace:

```
Started POST "/microposts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-05-21 11:41:31 +0100
[afb16a524c6d01fd7408e9944dbf30f9] [127.0.0.1] Processing by MicropostsController#create as JS
[afb16a524c6d01fd7408e9944dbf30f9] [127.0.0.1]   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"4KVkocVy4ONTrhQ7DqBWsJXcZC8uYDOjmv6C1DlcRxg=", "micropost"=>{"photo_attributes"=>{"photo_album_id"=>"25"}, "user_id"=>"2", "content"=>"lkkllk", "link"=>""}, "commit"=>"Post"}
[afb16a524c6d01fd7408e9944dbf30f9] [127.0.0.1]   User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
[afb16a524c6d01fd7408e9944dbf30f9] [127.0.0.1]    (0.1ms)  BEGIN
[afb16a524c6d01fd7408e9944dbf30f9] [127.0.0.1]   SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `microposts` (`content`, `created_at`, `image`, `link`, `poster_id`, `updated_at`, `user_id`) VALUES ('lkkllk', '2012-05-21 10:41:31', NULL, '', NULL, '2012-05-21 10:41:31', 2)
[afb16a524c6d01fd7408e9944dbf30f9] [127.0.0.1]    (0.3ms)  COMMIT
[afb16a524c6d01fd7408e9944dbf30f9] [127.0.0.1]   Micropost Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `microposts`.* FROM `microposts` WHERE `microposts`.`user_id` = 2 ORDER BY microposts.created_at DESC LIMIT 1
[afb16a524c6d01fd7408e9944dbf30f9] [127.0.0.1]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `microposts`.* FROM `microposts` WHERE `microposts`.`user_id` = 2 ORDER BY microposts.created_at DESC LIMIT 1
[afb16a524c6d01fd7408e9944dbf30f9] [127.0.0.1]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `microposts`.* FROM `microposts` WHERE `microposts`.`user_id` = 2 ORDER BY microposts.created_at DESC LIMIT 1
[afb16a524c6d01fd7408e9944dbf30f9] [127.0.0.1]   Profile Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `profiles`.* FROM `profiles` WHERE `profiles`.`user_id` = 2 LIMIT 1
[afb16a524c6d01fd7408e9944dbf30f9] [127.0.0.1]   Photo Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `photos`.* FROM `photos` WHERE `photos`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
[afb16a524c6d01fd7408e9944dbf30f9] [127.0.0.1]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `microposts`.* FROM `microposts` WHERE `microposts`.`user_id` = 2 ORDER BY microposts.created_at DESC LIMIT 1
[afb16a524c6d01fd7408e9944dbf30f9] [127.0.0.1]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `microposts`.* FROM `microposts` WHERE `microposts`.`user_id` = 2 ORDER BY microposts.created_at DESC LIMIT 1
[afb16a524c6d01fd7408e9944dbf30f9] [127.0.0.1]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `microposts`.* FROM `microposts` WHERE `microposts`.`user_id` = 2 ORDER BY microposts.created_at DESC LIMIT 1
[afb16a524c6d01fd7408e9944dbf30f9] [127.0.0.1]   Photo Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `photos`.* FROM `photos` WHERE `photos`.`micropost_id` = 4892 LIMIT 1
[afb16a524c6d01fd7408e9944dbf30f9] [127.0.0.1]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `microposts`.* FROM `microposts` WHERE `microposts`.`user_id` = 2 ORDER BY microposts.created_at DESC LIMIT 1
[afb16a524c6d01fd7408e9944dbf30f9] [127.0.0.1]    (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `comments` WHERE `comments`.`micropost_id` = 4892
[afb16a524c6d01fd7408e9944dbf30f9] [127.0.0.1]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `microposts`.* FROM `microposts` WHERE `microposts`.`user_id` = 2 ORDER BY microposts.created_at DESC LIMIT 1
[afb16a524c6d01fd7408e9944dbf30f9] [127.0.0.1]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `comments` WHERE `comments`.`micropost_id` = 4892
[afb16a524c6d01fd7408e9944dbf30f9] [127.0.0.1]   Photo Load (1.9ms)  SELECT `photos`.* FROM `photos` WHERE `photos`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
[afb16a524c6d01fd7408e9944dbf30f9] [127.0.0.1]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `microposts`.* FROM `microposts` WHERE `microposts`.`user_id` = 2 ORDER BY microposts.created_at DESC LIMIT 1
[afb16a524c6d01fd7408e9944dbf30f9] [127.0.0.1]   Rendered users/partials/_micropost.html.erb (19.3ms)
[afb16a524c6d01fd7408e9944dbf30f9] [127.0.0.1]   Rendered microposts/post_on_wall.js.erb (20.8ms)
[afb16a524c6d01fd7408e9944dbf30f9] [127.0.0.1] Completed 200 OK in 33ms (Views: 20.0ms | ActiveRecord: 4.5ms | Sphinx: 0.0ms)
```

I would really appreciate some insight to what could be going on so I can fix it.

Kind regards

Comment: Shouldn't you use partial rendering in your code? Just a guess.

Comment: In my code? Not sure what you mean.

Comment: In the js template `<%= j render(:partial => ..) %>`. Not sure, but it may render the whole layout, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails doesn't know what instance variable to render. Either pass @micropost in the :locals hash or just 'render @micropost'.

See this very helpful railscast for a great model: http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery